# tf.train.batch behavior for multiple epochs in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have a question about the behavior of tf.train.batch, if it is intended to provide batches for multiple epochs. I have a TFRecord with multiple SequenceExamples, which I want to process for a number of epochs.
I noticed that the batch operation accepts a parameter allow_smaller_final_batch. How I intended to run an epoch was as follows: write a loop that fetches a number of batches equal to the total number of examples divided by the batch size and run my model on thos batches.

My batches would be based on a string_input_queue which produces the same file name num_epoch numbers of times. My question now is: Will the final batch for each epoch be of a smaller size, with that parameter set, or will only the final batch of my final epoch be of a smaller size? Because if that is the case, I will get an OutOfRangeException before all of my epochs are finished, Ï would think.

So: how exactly does tf.train.batch handle cases like these? And is my approach the correct one for running multiple epochs, or is there a better one?

Comment: Only the final batch of your final epoch be of a smaller size. `tf.train.batch` doesn't know about the way data is produced and will receive the start of the first batch right after the last batch finished.